# Android Altbeaconlibrary. Beacon detection is very unreliable ~ 15%

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I am using the altbeacon library with 2 iBeacons. 
I downloaded the sample app for android studio from http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/ and added the iBeacon Layout ("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24").

When I start the ranging activity the beacons are detected - but very sporadic.
See:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63333482/Screenshot_20160322-191422.png

I also installed the Locater App - and it seems to be quite the same here.

I'm testing with HTC m8.

Has anyone an idea what could be the problems (Beacons, Mobilephone, etc.?)

Thanks

Comment: Altbeacon is fine, beacons are not reliable, if you need in detail answer let me know

Answer (score 0):

Remember that beacons send at a rather low frequency. Usually once a second if you haven't configured them. That means you will see loss of "pings". You need to use a timer per beacon or compare timestamp with current time to keep tab on real loss of communication.

What frequency (or rather interval) are they set for?

Do they have different IDs?

How far away are the beacons?

I'm not saying you can rule out phone problems though, as the series of zeros seems odd.

Cheers,
Anders